# Parse XML in Js for Website

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml

Hy!

I am very new in Web-Dev. I have a mysql db and the controller is made with PHP.

I give the data formated in php back to the html.

My Quest:

How to parse the xml in js right for the HTML based view?

If there are better solutions for the data transfair between PHP and HMTL, please let me know.
I don't wont the have HTML code in the php

Example PHP:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
        if (is_numeric($id))
        {
            include 'db_connect.php';
            $sql = "Select * from RECIPES WHERE recipes_id=".$id;
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or exit("QUERY FAILED!");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                 echo "<RECIPE>";
                 echo "<ID>" . $row['recipes_id'] . "</ID><br />";
                 echo "<TITLE>" . $row['text'] . "</TITLE><br />";
                 echo "<TEXT>" . $row['text'] . "</TEXT><br />";
                 echo "<COUNT_PERSONS>" . $row['count_persons'] . "</COUNT_PERSONS><br />";
                 echo "<DURATION>" . $row['duration'] . "</DURATION><br />";
                 echo "<USER_ID>" . $row['user_id'] . "</USER_ID><br />";
                 echo "<DATE>" . $row['date'] . "</DATE><br />";
                 echo "</RECIPE>";
             }
        }

        else
        {
                echo "<ERROR>ID ERROR</ERRORR>";
        }
        mysql_close($db);

?>
```

thx

Comment: Can you give some examples of the PHP code / XML / final result your expecting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to transfer data between the browser and the server then it's simpler to use the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. For PHP there are two built in function to decode and encode JSON: [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Modern browser support JSON by default: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings) and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Converting_objects_into_JSON).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with styrr, but if you must use XML then you can use [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) or simply use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with correct type eg.:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php?parameters=abc",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(responseDocument){
    var all_ids = responseDocument.getElementsByTagName('ID');
    var all_ids_jquery_way = $('ID', responseDocument);
  }
});
```

You can use any othe AJAX framework or even write your own function. Browsers can parse XML and create a document which you can then change as the main document (with DOM functions).

Again with most data JSON is a bit simpler to use and is lighter.